# Samba python scripting

Tags: python, archlinux, samba

I'm trying to write simple a python script for samba user management. I found this documentation with an [example](https://www.samba.org/~jelmer/samba4-python.pdf). This example uses a lib named "SAMR" (`import samr`). I have no idea where to get it or how to install it.

It does not exist in pip or easyinstall. Only samba setup.py file google finds is from 2007. I found a package name `python-samba` in debian repos, but I'm an arch user. There no such package in AUR or official repos.

Thanks

Comment: Since there is no exist resource in arch linux, if you still want to use arch to achieve this, you should make from source code or port rpm from other linux-distribution into arch.

Answer (score 0):

That code has since evolved. It is now located in `samba.dcerpc.samr`.

Every modern full Samba installation (like the one in arch) should come with the Python modules, though arch may install them in a non-standard path.